# ASP.NET MVC long Route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How I can to avoid route config like that?
I have an admin panel where user with administrator role is able to do some action(edit/delete/view) with different entities(users/profiles/addresses/...). 
And i want put all this action into 1 controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "EditProfile",
            url: "Account/Profiles/{id}/Edit",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "EditProfile" }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RemoveProfile",
            url: "Account/Profiles/{id}/Remove",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "RemoveProfile" }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "EditAddress",
            url: "Account/Addresses/{id}/Edit",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "EditAddress" }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RemoveAddress",
            url: "Account/Addresses/{id}/Remove",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "RemoveAddress" }
        );
//...
```

Basically I want replace all MapRoute to smth like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AccountProfileActions",
            url: "Account/{entities}/{id}/{subAction}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = {subAction} + {entities}}
        );
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't specify the action (or controller for that matter) and rely on MVC Route conventions, i.e. the controller name and action name will be part of the URL.

If you want to have a specific route that does not match up with your controller/action names, then consider using something like [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/), which will let you specify the route right on your controller/action, instead of having to go into RouteConfig each time.

Comment: Thanks. I think its better solution for this problem